XSLT transformation: move tag values to parent ones
could you support me with the following XSLT transformation:
Initial xml file:
<root>
    <Invoice>
        <ID>
            <_>INV12345</_>
        </ID>
        <InvoiceTypeCode>
            <_>01</_>
            <listVersionID>1.0</listVersionID>
        </InvoiceTypeCode>
        <InvoicePeriod>
            <StartDate>
                <_>2017-11-26</_>
            </StartDate>
            <EndDate>
                <_>2017-11-30</_>
            </EndDate>
        </InvoicePeriod>
        <AccountingSupplierParty>
            <AdditionalAccountID>
                <_>id-1234</_>
                <schemeAgencyName>name1</schemeAgencyName>
            </AdditionalAccountID>
        </AccountingSupplierParty>
    </Invoice>
</root>

Final xml file:
<Invoice>
    <ID>NV12345</ID>
    <InvoiceTypeCode listVersionID="1.0">01</InvoiceTypeCode>
    <InvoicePeriod>
        <StartDate>2017-11-26</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2017-11-30</EndDate>
    </InvoicePeriod>
    <AccountingSupplierParty schemeAgencyName="name1">
        <AdditionalAccountID>id-1234</AdditionalAccountID>
    </AccountingSupplierParty>
</Invoice>

It's necessary to do:

remove root tag;
remove all tags <_>, but their values move to their parent tags;
all others non <_> tags move as attributes to their parent tags.

Such task is happened while Jackson transformation of UBL (Universal Business Language) from JSON to XML.
I've just found how to remove the root tag:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- identity template --> 
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">   
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- remove root tag --> 
    <xsl:template match="/*">   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" /> 
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>


The result you show does not meet your own rules: the schemeAgencyName element is a child of AdditionalAccountID, but you made it into an attribute of its grandparent AccountingSupplierParty.

Yes, it's my mistake, thank you, @michael.hor257k

I believe I am getting the expected result using this XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <!-- convert leaf child elements (except _) to attributes -->
        <xsl:for-each select="*[not(* or self::_)]">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>  
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- process other child elements and text nodes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[*] | _ | text() "/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove root and _ elements --> 
<xsl:template match="/* | _">   
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

But this does not process comments and processing instructions.
Bear in mind that removing the root element could cause the result to become an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document.

I see a difference between your result and the one expected by the OP. But that seems to be because you followed the OP's stated rules - see my comment to the question.

Thank you, @y.arazim,
it seems it works perfectly fine.
And thank you for the notes: I do not need to process comments and instructions. And I'm sure that after removing the root tag I'll receive a well-formed XML file.

Only if you can be sure that the root element has only one child node.

You've stated three rules and these can all be expressed as template rules.
Start with an identity template, in 3.0 that's `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>; in earlier versions you have to spell it out explicitly but I see you've done that.
You've also done the first rule, for removing the root element.
The next one is:

remove all tags <_>, but their values move to their parent tags;

That's exactly the same as removing the root element:
<xsl:template match="_"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>

(you don't need to explicitly move the values to the parent element, that will happen automatically).
Finally:

all others non <_> tags move as attributes to their parent tags.

I guess (from your example) that by "all others" you mean all elements that have text-only content. This involves some reordering, so the rule has to be applied at the next level up. A handy trick here is to sort the child elements on a boolean condition (false sorts before true):
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:sort select="boolean(child::*)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(child::*)]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="."/>
</xsl:template>

or if you're still using 1.0,
<xsl:template match="*[not(child::*)]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>


Thank you @MichaelKay for the answer.
The 1nd transformation works perfectly fine.
The 2nd one is not compiled: "Unexpected attribute 'select' with value '.'"
The 3rd one produces an error: "Cannot add attribute ''='INV12345' to element 'ID'"_
